# Disabling MariaDB cluster multi master mode

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera, mariadb-10.1

Is it possible to configure replication with one master node and 2 slaves in MariaDB like replication works in mongodb? I noticed that the default is multi master mode. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. Standard replication configuration is master and single or multiple slaves. If you use MariaDB Galera cluster you can point your applications to a single node and the other two serves as slaves.

Comment: thanks. my mention of master relates to writes. I want to be sure that writes are not possible via slaves. After Galera was up, i saw that writes are possible via all the nodes. So it's multi master from the 'writes' point of view

Comment: writes are still possible, but you can set read_only=1 on the 'slave' nodes and remove SUPER privs on regular mysql accounts.